# Manage gemset for ruby project with rvm and bundler

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

I am new to ruby and I am trying to achieve the following.

When I run `bundle install` my project should have a gemset created with all the gem dependencies in the `Gemfile` of the project installed in the project gemset.

So I have the following files

- Gemfile
- .ruby-version
- .ruby-gemset

My .ruby-version looks like this

ruby-2.0.0

My .ruby-gemset files looks as follows

- my_service

And my Gemfile just has ruby gem dependencies

When I do `bundle install` and then do a `echo $GEM_HOME` my $GEM_HOME is still the default and when i do `rvm list` the current ruby version is `ruby-2.3.0` which is not what i specified in my .ruby-version file and when I go to ~/.rvm/gems I dont see my gemset in that folder.

What am I missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My .ruby-version looks like this
>
> ```
> ruby-2.0.0
> ```

According to the [rvm docs](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects#project-file-ruby-version), it should look like this:

```
2.0.0
```

The rvm scripts that employ those `.` files are triggered by the `cd` command--not the `bundle install` command. So try cd'ing out of your project directory, then back into it. Then check the things you checked before.

I just created a new rails project:

```
~/rails_projects$ rails new proj1
```

Then I created the `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` files in the project directory:

```
~/rails_projects$ cd proj1
~/rails_projects/proj1$ echo 1.9.3-p551 > .ruby-version
~/rails_projects/proj1$ echo proj1gemset > .ruby-gemset
```

After cd'ing out of the project directory, then back in, the rvm scripts that ran produced some output:

```
~/rails_projects/proj1$ cd

~$ cd rails_projects/proj1/
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #gemset created /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@proj1gemset
ruby-1.9.3-p551 - #generating proj1gemset wrappers..........
```

The next time you cd into the project directory, you won't see that output.

Subsequently, everything was setup correctly:

```
~/rails_projects/proj1$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-darwin14.5.0]

~/rails_projects/proj1$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p551 (found in /Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551)
   (default)
   global
=> proj1gemset

~/rails_projects/proj1$ echo $GEM_HOME
/Users/7stud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@proj1gemset

~/rails_projects/proj1$ ls ~/.rvm/gems
cache               
ruby-1.9.3-p551@proj1gemset
...
...
```

On the other hand, if you don't `cd` out of the project directory after creating the rvm `.` files, and instead you run `bundle install`, the gemset won't be created.

Comment: yeah cd 'ing out and coming back in makes the difference :). Thanks @7stud

Answer (score -1):

try to add

```
ruby 2.0.0
```

into your Gemfile